# OpenSuSE "forgets" screen setup on every boot

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde-4, opensuse-11.3

I am using OpenSuSE 11.3 and have a dual monitor setup. Graphicdrivers are completly untouched, I just took what came with the installation.

I use the default tool coming with KDE to manage my monitors and the only thing I have to do is to set the "Position" Property of my second monitor to "Left of DVI1". I then hit  "Accept" and the setup is exactly as I want it.

But after rebooting, the setup is forgotten and the monitors are clones again.

Could anyone tell me how what I seem to be missing?

Comment: What kind of gfx card are you using? I had the same problem in Ubuntu that was solved by some quick terminal scripts. Should apply similarly to OpenSuSE.

Comment: Damn, forgot to include that: A nVidia GTX 260.